# Who sees through the lens of mAyA?

Tags: brahman, advaita

Advait Vedantins say when Brahman is 'seen' through the lens of mAyA, Brahman appears as Ishwar.

Is there 'something' before mAyA to wear the lens of mAya? If there is, what is that 'something' which is wearing lens of mAyA? That 'something' can't be Brahman itself because according to Advait Vedanta Brahman has no activity, he can't 'see'. That 'something' can't be the Jiva because the Jiva appears after mAyA. I there a 'something' before mAyA?

What is that 'something' which is wearing lens of mAyA?

Comment: which is why hindu metaphysics is a morass.  when the hindu/buddhist enlightenment is emptiness - all wordy discourse on enlightenment would only be a mass of contradictions.  as krishnamurti says = if your mind is not empty, it is not in truth.

Comment: @SK Actually this logical impasse can be thrown out by considering Brahman as active.

Comment: anything you say about brahman without realizing brahman is just words @rajas.  reading and regurgitating someone else's words about brahman means little.

Comment: @SK Yes, I know it can't be talked of. But we should talk on it as far as we can. I don't believe in either extremes - That to talk only theoretically, mimicking scriptures without practicality or stop talking entirely saying Brahman is unfathomable. I believe theory & practicals should go hand in hand. And we can talk on Brahman as far as we can although it is incomprehensible.

Comment: @SK btw, you might be interested in Kashmiri Shaivism - another non dual Indian school where Shiva is Brahman & is active. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir_Shaivism

Comment: Are u looking for answers only from the pov of a particular man made philosophy? @Rajas.

Comment: @Rickross Yes, it's question on Advait Vedanta.

Comment: "That something can't be Jiva also because Jiva appears after mAyA", how are you saying that jiva appears after maya?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Before mAyA there is only Brahman.

Comment: Or in other words mAyA was there before Jiva @KrishnaShweta

Comment: you are overanalyzing metaphors. Mataphors work one way. 'Seeing' is a metaphor. Your question is written unclearly also. Please edit.

Comment: @Swami U can edit. I won't roll back unless it is against the spirit of the question. :)

Comment: There was no something to perceive before. See Brahma Sutras 1.1.5-11 and the last paragraph of commentary by Sankara prior to verse 1.1.5. Here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62753.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this question is in the last assertion that Jiva appears after maya and here something is before maya. This is taking an analogy literally.

> Advaita Vedanta says that ignorance of Brahman has created this world.
>   Ignorance, which is the opposite of knowledge (jnana-virodhi), is not
>   something negative. It has a positive character (bhavarupa). It has
>   two powers: (1) the veiling power (avarana-shakti) and (2) the power
>   of projection (vikshepa-shakti). Ignorance has the power to cover or
>   veil the Reality, which is Brahman, and also the power to project this
>   world on the veiled or covered Reality. **The world is the product of
>   mula-avidya. The individual ego, which is part of this world, is also
>   the product of mula-avidya. Consciousness associated with this ego is
>   called the Atman or the Jivatman. Between the Jivatman and Brahman
>   (Paramatman) there is a thin veil of ignorance. It is like a cloud
>   that does not allow an individual to see the sun. In this analogy the
>   Brahman is the sun and the patch of cloud is the ignorance of the
>   individual. When this individual’s ignorance is dispelled by the
>   knowledge of Brahman, he or she will have the experience of Brahman.**

Journey from many to one *essentials of Advaita Vedanta* by Swami Bhaskarananda

Comment: It is like a cloud that does not allow an individual to see the sun. In this analogy the Brahman is the sun and the patch of cloud is the ignorance of the individual. Why something is existing apart from the sun (Brahman)? From where 3rd person came? You are saying someone is seeing the sun means there are two ontologies - 1 sun 2 the one who is seeing the sun. Which is abuse of non duality. This analogy is also wrong then.

Comment: There should be only sun (Brahman )& clouds (Maya) when you are talking about AV. Not the 3rd entity which is seeing the sun.

Comment: And when for the sake of maintaining non duality, you establish only two ontological entities - sun & cloud. Then my question remains intact who is seeing through the cloud as sun can't see according to AV.

Comment: Firstly it is not correct to say that the sun (Brahman) can't see. Nirguna Brahman of AV is pure consciousness or awareness. So it is aware of everything in dualistic language. Secondly the cloud is not an ontological entity. The cloud is a cloud of unknowing. The analogy is trying to say that Brahman (jiva) is unaware that It is Brahman due to its cloud of ignorance. When Brahman (jiva) knows or in other words the cloud of ignorance disperses, then Brahman (jiva) knows itself.

Comment: Sir, it is aware of its existence. Can you cite some reference. I'm curious to read on this more.

Comment: Read Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 4.5.15 where it is said, 'Through what should one know That because of which all this is known. .... Through what, my dear, should one know the knower.'   Nirguna Brahman seated in our heart allows us to know eveything. If you assume that Nirguna Brahman can not 'see' or is not aware then you will have the very puzzling situation that some entity which  cannot see or is not aware makes us 'see' or be aware of everything. This is the argument given by Shankara in his commentary on Brahma Sutra III.ii.21..

Comment: Okay. Then what do you mean by Brahman is inactive?

Comment: It means Brahman is a non-doer. It is Prakriti or Brahman's Shakti which does everything regarding the universe and its living beings.. Go through Gita 9.8, 9.9 and 9.10 which explains the situation.

Comment: Omg. Brahman even has Shakti also. :O ... Okay, gonna read VivekA chudambini first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how AdI Shankaracharya addresses the question of who has Avidya, in [this section](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24248/36) of his Brahma Sutra Bhashya:

> And should you ask who then is characterised by the absence of true knowledge, we reply: You yourself who ask this question!--And if you retort, 'But I am the Lord as declared by scripture,' we reply, 'Very well, if you have arrived at that knowledge, then there is nobody who does not possess such knowledge.'--This also disposes of the objection, urged by some, that a system of non-duality cannot be established because the Self is affected with duality by Nescience.

So Adi Shankaracharya's answer is that from the relative perspective, i.e.the perceptive of someone who has Avidya, it is the Jiva who has Avidya, but from the absolute perspective, i.e. the perspective of someone who does not have Avidya, nobody has Avidya. That is why Gaudapada says this in chapter 2 of the Mandukya Karika:

> na nirodho na cotpattirna baddho na ca sādhakaḥ | 
>   na mumukṣurna vai mukta ityeṣā paramārthatā ||
>
> There is neither dissolution nor creation, none in bondage and none practicing disciplines. There is none seeking Liberation and none liberated. This is the absolute truth.

But other members of the Vedanta school have not found this sort of response satisfactory, and have given rebuttals of it, for instance in the Jijnasa Adhikarana of Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya and in Vedanta Desikan's Satadhushani.

Comment: Weird...I am not getting him completely. Something seems missing in his arguments.